# Understanding Windows stack layout

Tags: c, windows, buffer-overflow

I am following this buffer overflow tutorial: https://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

I want to make this program work in Windows

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int x, int y)
{
    char buffer1[5];
    char buffer2[10];
    int *ret = buffer1 + 12;
    (*ret) += 7;
}

int main()
{
    int x;

    x = 10;
    f(1, 2);
    x = 21;
    printf("%d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

This program attempts to modify the return address of function `f` so that this line `x = 21;` is ignored in `main` (ie. the program jumps directly to executing `printf`).

For some reason this trivial buffer overflow attack didn't work in Windows and I am not sure why.

This is how I understand the stack layout after the function `f` is called in x64 machines

```
high address
...
return address (4 bytes)
saved frame pointer (4 bytes)
1 (first argument for f; 4 bytes)
2 (second argument for f; 4 bytes)
buffer1 (1*8=8 bytes)
buffer2 (1*12=12 bytes)
...
low address
```

Using gdb, I get the following disassembly

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000401590 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000401591 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000401594 <+4>:     sub    $0x30,%rsp
   0x0000000000401598 <+8>:     callq  0x401690 <__main>
   0x000000000040159d <+13>:    movl   $0xa,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00000000004015a4 <+20>:    mov    $0x2,%edx
   0x00000000004015a9 <+25>:    mov    $0x1,%ecx
   0x00000000004015ae <+30>:    callq  0x401560 <f>
   0x00000000004015b3 <+35>:    movl   $0x15,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00000000004015ba <+42>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x00000000004015bd <+45>:    mov    %eax,%edx
   0x00000000004015bf <+47>:    lea    0x2a3a(%rip),%rcx        # 0x404000
   0x00000000004015c6 <+54>:    callq  0x402b70 <printf>
   0x00000000004015cb <+59>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004015d0 <+64>:    add    $0x30,%rsp
   0x00000000004015d4 <+68>:    pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004015d5 <+69>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

So in order to get return address in the stack, I must add 4+4+4=12 bytes. From the disassembly, in order to skip `x = 21;`, I must skip `movl   $0x15,-0x4(%rbp)`. So I need to add the additional  42-35=7 bytes to the return address.

Is there anything wrong with my understanding so far?

Comment: The compiler decided to use fastcall for your internal function.

Comment: @Anders What's this?

Comment: Windows (x86) has a bunch of calling conventions, the official ones are stdcall, cdecl and fastcall (borderline official). The compiler will add thiscall and others onto this list for internal functions.

Comment: Which compiler?  By default Visual Studio compiles with `/GS` unless explicitly forced off with `/GS-`.  Otherwise, the assumptions about `x` being consistently 12 bytes away from `buffer1` is going to be compiler depedenent.

Comment: @selbie I'm using tdm gcc